# ViewPager with dynamic contents

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am using the method suggested [here](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/) in order to implement swipeable tabs in Android using the SupportV4 library. In order to initialise the ViewPager, one has to create a page adapter which needs to be filled with a list of fragments/tabs, each associated with an activity, as shown here:

```
/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
private void intialiseViewPager() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

My question is: how can I dynamically populate the fragments list with tabs not associated with any class. For example a list of tabs in which the header of the tabs are obtained from an string array

Comment: `PagerAdapter` is an interface -- you cannot create an instance of it, per your `new PagerAdapter()` call above.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the class name PagerAdapter cannot be used as it is being used by android(or something like that) so I use the class name ViewPagerAdapter...
Modify your pager adapter to something like this...

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<TabInfo> tabs;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = new ArrayList<tabInfo>();
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return tabs.get(i).fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position).title;
    }
    public class TabInfo {
        public Fragment fragment;
        String title;
    }
    public void addTab(Fragment _fragment, String _title) {
        final TabInfo _tabInfo = new tabInfo();
        _tabInfo.fragment=_fragment;
        _tabInfo.title = _title;
        tabs.add(_pageInfo);
    }
```

and your initialise to this...

```
private void intialiseViewPager() {
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerAdapter.addTab(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
    mPagerAdapter.addTab(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
    mPagerAdapter.addTab(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

I use ArrayList as it has an index and I am comfortable with it, you can use any indexed list type as per your need.

Comment: FYI: FragmentPagerAdapter is a subclass of PagerAdapter. PagerAdapter is an abstract class which helps manage the content to show in a ViewPager.